# A div element goes down

Tags: css

I have a questions. I learn coding and I have not found any answer on this web-site.

I have three `<div>` elements in the `<body>`. Two `<div>` elements need to float to the left, and a third `<div>` - to the right. The right `<div>` went down. I need it go to the top. Below you can find code and a picture

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-Us">

<head>

<title>Архив Луганской области</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<style>
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:0.8em;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px 60px 0px 60px;
 }

#line {
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 }

#contacts {
 float:left;
 width:800px;
 vertical-align:top;
 }

#container {

 float:right;
 }

#services {
 
 width:500px;
 position:relative;
 }

#news {
 width:500px;
 border-left:4px solid #C4C4C4;
 position:relative;
 }



</style>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>


<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(48.569725,39.321948),
    zoom:8,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>



</head>
```

```html
<body>

<div id="head">
<h3>Украина, Луганск<h3>
</div>

<div id="line">

<hr> </hr>

</div>

<div id="contacts">

<h5>Режим работы</h5>
<pre><h2>Пон-Суб   7:00-22:00</h2></pre>

<h5 title="Позвоните и Закажите!">Телефон</h5>
<h2> +7 (978) 768-94-69</h2>
<h2>Совгыря Федор</h2>


<h5> E-mail:</h5>
<h2>fedor.sovgirya@gmail.com</h2>

<h5>Мессенджер</h5>
<h2> Skype sovgirya.fedor </h2>

<h5>Адрес:</h5>

<h2> Украина, г. Луганск, ул. Советская, 17 </h2>

</div>



<div id="container">

<div id="services">

<h3>Совгыря Федор Николаевич</h3>

<p> 

1) Составление родословной Вашего рода;
<br>2) Поиск биографии партийных и репрессированных членов семьи;
<br>3) Поиск фильтрационных дел родственников, угнанных в Германию в ВОВ; 
<br>4) поиск любой другой информации хранящейся в архивах Луганска и Луганской области.
<p>

</div>

<br> <br/>

<div id="news">
<h4>Новости</h4>

<p>10.01.2015 - Мы начали работать с архивами Луганска и Луганской области! <br>В случае отсутствия доступа к архивным документам по причине нестабильной ситуации, мы напишем объявлние в этом разделе. </p>

</div>

</div>



<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: I don't think it's very clear which 2 divs you want floating left.  I only see "contacts" with float: left;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The floats are working correctly, your `width` on the left elements is simply very large so with a smaller resolution the right element gets pushed down. Reduce the width on `contacts` and you should see what you want.

See [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/opw54ze4/)

I also added a `wrapper` with an explicitly set `width` to show that your code is working fine on large resolutions.